# Detecting of keydown combination Ctrl+= (Ctrl+Key.OemPlus)

Tags: wpf, keydown, ctrl

I have a `RichTextBox` control and I need to handle <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> keydown combination. <kbd>=</kbd> sign itself is `Key.OemPlus`.  So the problem is that when I press this combination, the `KeyDown` event is not raised.

I tried different code variants, with `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` for both pressed keys, with `Keyboard.Modifiers` for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, etc...

```cs
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.OemPlus) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
{
     // do smth
}
```

```cs
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.OemPlus) && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
     // do smth
}
```

```cs
if (args.Key == Key.OemPlus && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
{
     // do smth
}
```

```cs
if (args.Key == Key.OemPlus && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
     // do smth
}
```

So, none of the above code attempts worked and I can't find the answer in Google. How to solve this problem?

Comment: The order of pressed keys has to be: 1. Ctrl; 2.= (Key.OemPlus)

Comment: How you detect the keypress event?

Comment: are you using KeyDown or PreviewKeyDown event?

Comment: I am using KeyDown event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic WPF routed event problem. The `KeyDown` routed event is being [handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling) by the `RichTextBox` internally. It thinks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> is a command that it recognized, so it eats the `KeyDown` event before it gets to you. Luckily there is a solution: `PreviewKeyDown`. If you change your code to handle `PreviewKeyDown` instead of `KeyDown` you should find that the events fire as you expect.